# DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: vue.js

I am having an issue with a [third party library](https://dafrok.github.io/vue-baidu-map/#/en/index).

I wrote a `component` to watch the `position` property and call the `reload` method to refresh the overlays on the map.

It performed normal when there is only [one v-for](http://jsfiddle.net/tb4sap2c/22/).

But failed when there is [two v-for](http://jsfiddle.net/tb4sap2c/21/).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap every `v-for` directive in it's own, dedicated parent `div`.

Each `v-for` directive expands into multiple elements. If there are multiple lists with the same parent element which need to be updated at the same time, Vue is having a hard time updating the virtual dom.

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not only happen with multiple `v-for`s in one component; I also came across it when using multiple root elements in `nuxt3`. I fixed the issue by using old-style `vue2` syntax: Every `template` contains only **one** child element (or `v-for`-directive), which contains all the content.

TL;DR: Wrapping complex contents (`v-for`, content of a page > 1 element, ...) in another surrounding `div` might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when an html element with v-if didn't have a parent container