# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': when updating value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've this list of items I'm trying to change the UI when I press the confirm button, but it's throwing an error and the UI doesn't get updated till I refresh the page, can someone help me out here.?

I'm using `v-if` to change the buttons and all depending on the status I get from DB.

```js
confirm_Product(item) {
      let index = this.order.products.findIndex(
        (product) => product.product_code === item.product_code
      );
      this.order.products[index].status = 1
      console.log((this.order.products[index].status = 1));
    }
```

```html
      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              v-if="item.status === 0"
              class="ma-2"
              right
              color="green"
              dark
              small
              @click="confirm_Product(item)"
              style="width: 8rem"
            >
              <v-icon medium class="mr-2" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                mdi-checkbox-marked-outline </v-icon
              >Confirm
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              v-if="item.status === 0"
              class="ma-2"
              right
              color="red"
              dark
              small
              @click="rejectItem(item)"
              style="width: 8rem"
            >
              <v-icon medium class="mr-2" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                mdi-cancel </v-icon
              >Reject
            </v-btn>
            <v-chip v-if="item.status === 1" color="success" outlined
              >Confirmed</v-chip
            >
            <v-chip
              v-if="item.status === 2"
              color="primary"
              @click="viewShippingDetails(item)"
              link
              outlined
              pill
              >View Shipping details
              <v-icon right> mdi-arrow-right </v-icon>
            </v-chip>
          </template>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
```

[image]

Comment: actually, I was calling an API there too but removed it from the time being, coz API returns success but I couldn't change my UI

Comment: Pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653178/vue-warn-error-in-nexttick-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-insertbefore and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357091/domexception-failed-to-execute-insertbefore-on-node-the-node-before-which

Answer (score 0):

changed the `v-if`s to `v-show` looks like it's working now.